# Check if product is already selected then alert user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    Quantity1: <input type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1">
    Product1: <select name="product1" id="product1"><option value="1">Product 1</option><option value="2">Product 2</option> ... <option value="15">Product 15</option></select>
    Price1: <input type="text" name="price1" id="price1">
    Quantity2: <input type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity2">
    Product2: <select name="product1" id="product2"><option value="1">Product 1</option><option value="2">Product 2</option> ... <option value="15">Product 15</option></select>
    Price2: <input type="text" name="price2" id="price2">
    .
    .
    .
    Quantity15: <input type="text" name="quantity15" id="quantity15">
    Product15: <select name="product15" id="product15"><option value="1">Product 1</option><option value="2">Product 2</option> ... <option value="15">Product 15</option></select>
    Price15: <input type="text" name="price15" id="price15">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want to check if product is already selected then alert the user that this is selected.
It should be like this as i guess

```
$('select[id^="product"]').change(function() {
     //empty array
     var selected_values = array();
     //check value if it is in array then alert 
     if ($(this).val() IS IN ARRAY) {
         var product = $(this).text();
         alert("you have already select this"+product);
     } else {
         // else save it in array 
         selected_values[] = $(this).val();
     }
}
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/GKTYE/ but this alerts on submit i want to be on select change. Please help!

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery code...

Comment: Where are the Javascript parts?

Comment: When do you want to alert the user? Before they hit submit or after?

Comment: Sorry guyz I hav't any javascript code. :( I am new to javascript. I want them to alter once the select the option that was already selected.

Answer (score 3):

Add a method for the alert.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alertUser (productName, productSize) {
        // some method body
alert("You have selected a product: " + productName + "\r\nSize: " + productSize);
        }
    </script>
```

Within the desired select tag insert the method under the select tag attribute "on change" supply the method name.

```
<select name="product1" id="product1" onchange="alertUser('product1', 'Large')">
```

What this will do is that the alertUser() method gets called when the user changes the selection. You would need to write an if statement to determine when the desired option has been selected. You could write a function that handle multiple case, and speed up script writing by using arguments to increase the usability of the code.

Comment: Have you worked in any other programming language or are you new to programming (this excludes HTML)? Your answer will make it easier for me to help you.

Comment: Yes i know php and c++ but zero in javascript

Comment: Sweet. Javascript is a weak typed language, which basically means you don't have to declare your variable types. Functions are called in response to user events. Essentially, all you have to do is place function names inside the tag of an HTML object that a user is interacting with. These interactions include "onclick", "onmouseover", and much more. For example, if I want the background color of a div to change when a user mouses is on top of the div, you would insert a function like this:

Comment: <div id="specialOffer" onmouseover="changeColor(red);"> This is a special offer, click now!</div> You can check out other interactions at http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp this is where all the documentation is. Unlike C++ and php, we have to get the object through the Document Object Model

Comment: I have added some jquery code. I want somehting like http://jsfiddle.net/GKTYE/ but want to alert on select change.

Comment: I would 'grab' an html element and put it inside a variable like so: var myElement = document.getElementById("specialOffer"); Now that we have an html element we can use dot syntax to set certain properties of the element, such as its innerHTML: myElement.innerHTML = "New Special offer";

Comment: With this specific code in mind, you have a logical error inside the condition of your if statement. You not only need to check whether the each select tag has a selected option, you must also compare the results of the first select field with the second select field. Grab the value of the options selected within each select tag, and then compare if they are equal (==). If they are, then you display the desired error message.

Comment: I recommend not using jQuery until you have a firm grasp of JavaScript alone. In my opinion, JavaScript is a funky language that has certain ways of doing thing. jQuery adds other levels of complexity and requires a deeper understanding of their API to use it successfully.